# How do I suppress 'Execution optimizations have been disabled' warnings in Gradle 7?

Tags: gradle

After upgrading to Gradle 7 I have many warnings like:

```
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':<...>:compileJava' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '<...>\build\classes\main'. Reason: Task ':<...>:compileJava' uses this output of task ':<...>:processResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

The cause: I redirect output of resources to the same folder as class files - for integration tests reading resources:

```
sourceSets {
    main { 
        output.resourcesDir = file("build/classes/main") 
        java.outputDir = file("build/classes/main") 
    }
    test { 
        output.resourcesDir = file("build/classes/test") 
        java.outputDir = file("build/classes/test") 
    }
}
```

How do I suppress those warnings?

Comment: My guess is you shouldn't have two different tasks producing their 'output' to the same location. Found a bit of reasoning behind this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-7-0-seems-to-take-an-overzealous-approach-to-inter-task-dependencies/39656/2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way of how to suppress specific warnings, like lets say deprecation warnings only.

I am skipping those warnings with [-q flag for the command line](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#setting_log_level). Just to be aware that in this case all the warnings will be suppressed.

Example: `gradlew build -q`

At least you should create tasks to get rid of this technical debt. But then in the meantime you could use `-q` flag for your builds to avoid this additional noise. After the issues are resolved you remove `-q` flag.

Note that I also tried to use [--warning-mode none flag](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings) which didn't work for deprecation warning.